# Unity Match3 style game with letters (gemeration algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, random

I am making a match3 game, but with letters. Instead of combining 3 of the same blocks, you need to make valid words. 
My problem is if i generate the upcoming letters randomly, there is a huge chance not to be a valid word in the board or making it way too easy to find them.

Can you please suggest tips for an algorithm which can handle this problem?